# Resize Image using JMagick

Tags: java, dll, imagemagick, jmagick

I want to resize image using JMagick.

```
import magick.ImageInfo;
import magick.MagickImage;

public class JMagicInfoa {
    public static void main(String args[]){
    try{
        ImageInfo origInfo = new ImageInfo(args[0]); //load image info
        MagickImage image = new MagickImage(origInfo); 
        image = image.scaleImage(1000, 1000);
        image.setFileName(args[1]); //give new location
        image.writeImage(origInfo);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

I am experiencing below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: D:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.6-Q16\jmagick.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1778)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1703)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1030)
    at magick.MagickLoader.<clinit>(MagickLoader.java:13)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at magick.Magick.<clinit>(Magick.java:21)
    at JMagicInfo.JMagicInfoa.main(JMagicInfoa.java:10)
```

I searched for 64-bit, **JMagick.dll**, but could not found anywhere.

Is there any alternative to run this on 64-bit Machines.

**EDIT**

I replaced 64-bit JDK with 32-bit and now experiencing below error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: D:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.6-Q16\jmagick.dll: %1 is not a valid Win32 application
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
```

**Second EDIT**

Above code is working as expected on 32-bit machines. It is not working only on 64-bit machines.

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

You can try use 32-bit version of JDK. It works for me

Comment: I am experiencing this error: D:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.6-Q16\jmagick.dll: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Answer (score 0):

You should put the jmagick.dll in the C:\Windows\SysWOW64 so the the dll will link to other 32 bit dll. Also put the following parameter in the VM parament -Djava.library.path="C:\Windows\SysWOW64"